# Why are these destructors not being called during an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

According to the output, `~Foo` is only called for object `c`

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    const char * m_name;

    Foo (const char * name) : m_name (name) {}

    ~ Foo ()
    {
        std::cerr << m_name << bool(std::current_exception ()) << std::endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo a ("a");
    {
        Foo b ("b");
        {
            Foo c ("c");
        }
        throw 0;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
```

Why are the other objects not being destroyed? I thought this was supposed to happen.